# Recover deleted partition using testdisk

Tags: partition, testdisk

Last night I was not as awake as I thougt i was and I ended up formatting the wrong drive using GParted.....

I thought of testdisk to recover the lost partition but I don't really understand how to use it.

First of all Testdisk detect the partition table of my drive as "none" where as it should be detected as Intel (in my opinion)
[image: Partition table]

If I select an Intel partition type and then  analyse --> deeper search it showing in the first second of the scan the correct (backup superblock ?) of my "Lacie1To" partition witch used to be the only Ext4 partition occupying all the disk.

[image]

But if I clicked on stop it doesn't show me the partition in the list.

So my question, what should I do with this info ?

Answer (score 0):

You have surely deleted the MBR/GPT block of your disk (Block 0 of whole disk). You can try to copy with a hexeditor (`wxHexedit`) the Superblock from the locations on disk back to the original position

**BUT** In your case I would ASAP

1. Get 2 (!) another - same - sized harddisk
2. Download a UBCD ISO and burn it to CD/put it onto USB and run it
3. make a backup of your accidential formatted disk with `ddrescue <formatted drive>` `<new drive #1>` (put in the disk names like /dev/sda etc.). Takes upto 24 hours!
4. Run then `qphotorec` on to the formatted drive with destination on new drive #2 (make this - but only this - drive usable with windows etc. format)
5. If you don't understand anything what here written, get asap to your next Linux GURU :)

Seriously: if you haven't backup/written the GPT/MBR/block/CHS start adresses of your partitions as you installled your disk at first time, it's really hard to create a new MBR/GPT Block (using hexdeditors, gpart etc). In your case the qphotorec (recovers almost all files) is the best and easiest way

Comment: I'm interested in using wxHexedit be didn't find any tutorial, do you have any link ?

1) Shiping of HDD2 in progress !
2) I don't need a live cd or else, there where only data on it and no os so the computer can still boot without any problem.
3) backup on HDD1 in progress !
4) I've tried with recuva who found the files and restored them but without the name or the path....
5) That's the problem, i'm supposed to be the Linux Guru ;)

Comment: Try linux "gpart" (NOT gparted!!!). It's rather an older linux shell appication, which scans the whole disk for partitions an prints them (I think,  EXT3 etc. it will find, but not new stuff like BTRFS)
Current wxHexEdit (Debian) has a big bug (which I - as far I have some time -I'll fix), so try using Okteta (You have to install KDesktop package). Before you try to create a new MBR/GPT, have a look how an GPT/MBR is build up (GPT is easier). In Okteta then try to open the disk, look for the blocks of disk and backup on your OS disk. Then create a new one with the data of gpart (NOT gparted)

Comment: If Recuva did recover all files on an extra disk, you are on the sure site. For pictures there are some linux scripts which try to recover the picture name by the content tags (even for mp3). For Microsoft files are there programs too, which renames the files by their content. But before you get in the renaming files hell, backup all files again you've recovered